What is the max_tokens number I can put for OpenAI GPT generate function?
I've tried to use 100_000, 20_000 but seems like only 10_000 is possible:
from openai import OpenAI
client = OpenAI()

messages = {"role": "user", "content": "Hello"}

completion = client.chat.completions.create(
        model="gpt-4o-mini", messages=messages,
        max_tokens=10_000
    )

print(completion.choices[0].message.content)

There's the doc on https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/chat/create#chat-create-max_tokens but there's no clear indication of what's the largest max_tokens value possible.

From the API Doc you linked to:

The maximum number of tokens that can be generated in the chat completion.
The total length of input tokens and generated tokens is limited by
the model's context length.

I do agree this is kindof confusing.
There are currently multiple limited in place:

Maximum model input tokens
Maximum model output tokens
Maximum model context length (input tokens + output tokens)

Whichever limit is hit first will stops the generation of the output tokens at that point.
So the MaxTokens limit will be input prompt token length dependant.
i.e. max_tokens limit = Min(Maximum model output tokens, (Maximum model context length - Prompt Token Length))
So unless you calculating your prompt token length or you are asking it to generate fixed length output I would recommend you don't specify the max_tokens parameter.  I've found it always works fine without it anyway.
--- update ---
The maximum allowed number DEPENDS.
If you look at the model page at the gpt-4o model.
You can see:

Model - gpt-4o
Context window - 128,000 tokens
Max output tokens - 4,096 tokens

So the maximum input prompt tokens + output tokens can not exceed 128,000 tokens.
The maximum output tokens generated can't exceed 4,096 tokens.
So for a input prompt token length is less than 123,904 tokens (128,000 - 4,096) the maximum max_token variable can be up to 4,096.
If the input prompt greater than 123,904 tokens then the maximum max_token variable can be up to the remaining token count up to the maxumum 128,000 tokens.  i.e. if you input prompt token length was 127,800 tokens then the max_token maximum would be 200. i.e. 127,800 + 200 == 128,000 - the maxumum context window size.
You then need to apply this to the token size limits of the specific model you are dealing with.

But what's the maximum allowed number?

Updated answer with example of how to work out the maximum allowed number.
